# Unreal Engine: как двигать объект вдоль сплайна?

Tags: unreal-engine-4

В моей игре есть некий Blueprint Actor, один на всю игру. На каждом уровне создаются его экземпляры, которые должны двигаться вдоль заданной траектории. На каждом уровне траектории разные. Для разных экземпляров на одном уровне траектории могут быть разные.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Я посмотрел проект ContentExamples. Там на карте Blueprint_Splines есть разные примеры. Но в них используются сплайн как компонент того же самого актора. Но если я сделаю сплайн компонентом этого же Blueprint, то непонятно как его сделать различным для разных уровней. Ведь если я поменяю его в одном уровне, он поменяется везде. Или это не так?

Answer (score 0):

Создаете сплайн на каждый уровень. В каждом сплайне (могут быть child и наследоваться от первого, parent) установить переменную актор, сделать ее доступной  на панели details, чтобы после размещения сплайна и актора на уровне, можно было выбирать пипеткой на панели details нужный актор, который должен двигаться вдоль сплайна.